# What is the best practice for setting JPEG metadata for CC-BY-NC licensed pictures?

Tags: metadata, licensing, creative-commons

I want to publish my pictures with a CC-BY-NC license but I could not find a tutorial how store this information with my JPEG metadata.

Is there a best practice? Do services like Flickr, Google+ or Facebook read this information?

Comment: Creative Commons has guidance on the use of XMP metadata to store licensing information. (This isn't a complete answer because it doesn't address how online services use the information. It would also be nice to discuss how to enter the metadata in Lightroom or other tools.) http://wiki.creativecommons.org/XMP

Comment: I have a proof-of-concept (but working) Python script for this... would it be OT ;-)?

Comment: @Rmano I love scripting, so do it! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @coneslayer notes, Creative Commons does indeed [provide guidance for XMP information](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/XMP).

The main thing is to set **xmpRights:UsageTerms** to *This work is licensed to the public under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license [http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by­sa/2.0/](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/bysa/2.0/) verify at [http://example.com/pdf­metadata.html](http://example.com/pdfmetadata.html)*

That "verify" link is optional and should be a web site explaining the licensing in more detail. If you have such a web page, you should also set **xmpRights:WebStatement** to that URL.

They also recommend duplicating **xmpRights:UsageTerms** into **dc:rights**, because some people might use that tag instead.

You also can and should set XMP properties using Creative Commons' own schema, which defines **cc:license**, **cc:morePermissions** (for possible other allowed uses), **cc:attributionURL**, and **cc:attributionName**.

Answer (score 3):

Use [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to add exif metadata easily from console. It is easy to install, already present in popular Linux distros (e.g. Ubuntu)

```
$ exiftool -by-line="[your name]" -CopyrightNotice="© [your name] ; \
            Licence: Creative Commons cc-by-nc 3.0 United States \
            (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/us/)" \
            -artist="[your name]" -Copyright="© [your name] ; \
            Licence: Creative Commons cc-by-nc 3.0 United States \
            (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/us/)" \
            TARGET-IMAGE.JPG
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Photoshop you can go to File > File Info - This will allow you to include copyright data in the JPEG Metadata.

I am not aware of how services like Flickr, Google or Facebook handle metadata so I cannot comment there.

Answer (score 0):

I use this little script, which you can easily adapt. It need Python2.6 (does not work with Python3 because FWIK the pyexiv2 library has not a Python3 version). This come pre-installed with practically all linux distributions; you may need to add the package  `python-pyexiv2` in some of them. No idea on how to install on windows.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
import sys
import pyexiv2
#
fimage = sys.argv[1]
metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata(fimage)
metadata.read()
my_name = "Romano Giannetti"
my_email = "romano.giannetti@gmail.com"
copyr = "(c) " + my_name + " <" + my_email + ">" + ", All Rights Reserved" 
#
# set exif: 
#
exif_a="Exif.Image.Artist"
exif_r="Exif.Image.Copyright"
metadata[exif_a]=pyexiv2.ExifTag(exif_a, my_name)
metadata[exif_r]=pyexiv2.ExifTag(exif_r, copyr)
#
# set XMP
#
key_auth="Xmp.dc.creator"
key_rights="Xmp.dc.rights"
metadata[key_auth]=pyexiv2.XmpTag(key_auth, (my_name, my_email))
metadata[key_rights]=pyexiv2.XmpTag(key_rights, copyr)
#
metadata.write()
```

I think is more or less self-explicative: if you need to change/add Xmp tags, you simply do

```
keytag_name="Xmp.tag.name"
metadata[keytag_name]=pyexiv2.XmpTag(keytag_name, "this is the tag content")
```